# Add possibility to edit a topic request in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I've created a request for a topic in Documentation and received some comments on the request. I would love to edit my request and enhance the request with the suggested improvements. In the chat Quill told me that editing documentation requests is not possible ....

Please make it possible to edit your topic request

Comment: I have the exact same request but for a spelling mistake I made in my topic request description. Any ideas @Bascy whether this was ever addressed?

Comment: @Danoram Never had any reaction on this